# make Content_tag to print two elements in same line(Rails)

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, content-tag

```
content_tag(:p, "link : ") + content_tag(:p, link_to("abc","www.abc.com"))
```

This prints

```
link:
abc
```

But I want it to print

```
link: abc
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<p>`(Paragraph) is a block element and it's HTML mechanics (so it always takes the whole width of it's container). It doesn't have any relation to ruby/rails code and you can't achieve it making any changes in ruby code. You can achieve with some hacky CSS solutions. But good solution is to go with inline `<span>` tags. It will do what you want. And you can use single `<p>` as root element for 2 `<span>`

Answer (score 0):

Just use `display: inline-block` on the element. This is not a Rails issue but a CSS quirk. p is a block element, as in it takes the whole width of the parent unless its inline.

```css
.two p { display: inline-block; }
```

```html
<div class="one"><p>Hello</p><p>World</p></div>
<div class="two"><p>Hello</p><p>World</p></div>
```